# How to use GSON with no names?

Tags: java, php, json

I am using GSON to decrypt some JSON that I get from a PHP site, with the layout of:

```
[{"bellname":"Hey!","date":"2013-09-11"},{"bellname":"Haaaaey!","date":"2013-09-01"}]
```

I want to put this into a HashMap, and have seen that I need to create a class to do this. That is the part that I do not understand. This is what I have so far:

```
public class MySQLDB {
    private BellName bellName;
    private BellDate bellDate;

    public static class BellName {
        private String bn;
    }

    public static class BellDate {
        private String date;
    }
}
```

Where would I go from here? If you need to see my PHP code, here it is:

```
<?php

mysql_connect("localhost", "*******", "******");
mysql_select_db("tests");

$q1 = mysql_query("SELECT `bellname`, `date` FROM `bells`");

if($q1) {
    $que1 = array();

    while($a1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($q1)) {
        $que1[] = $a1;
    }

    $json1 = json_encode($que1);

    echo $json1;
}

?>
```

All this PHP code does is put a "mysql_fetch_assoc" reply into JSON.

Please help, if you could tell me how to fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to use List<Map<String, String>> to unmarshal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public class MySQLEntry {
    public String bellname;
    public String date;
}
// ...
Gson gson = new Gson();
MySQLEntry[] entryArray = gson.fromJson(yourJsonString, MySQLEntry[].class);
```

Answer (score 1):

Answer by jpossi is the most appropriate. But just for you to know json object could be represented as Map in Java. And json array could be represented as List. So in your case you also can do this:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
    Type type = new TypeToken<List<Map<String,String>>>(){}.getType();
    List<Map<String, String>> value = gson.fromJson("[{\"bellname\":\"Hey!\",\"date\":\"2013-09-11\"},{\"bellname\":\"Haaaaey!\",\"date\":\"2013-09-01\"}]", type);
    System.out.println(value);
```

But deserializing in object is better then deserializing in collection of Strings in most cases.